# find permission denied while erasing a temporary file of a certain user

Tags: bash, shell-script, permissions

I have to write a script that runs at startup (this is a part that I don't know how to do yet) that erases the temporary files of the current user and I have the "Permission denied" error. 
The errors look like this:

```
'/tmp/systemd-private-long number-colord.service-LTsv8G' : permission denied ;
'/tmp/systemd-private-long number-systemd-timesyncd.service-PxhNq0' : permission denied ;
'/tmp/systemd-private-long number-rtkit-daemon.service-KQN6zN' : permission denied
```

This is my code so far:

```
TMPFILE=$(mktemp)|| exit 1
find /tmp -type f -user $USER -exec rm -f {} \;
```

if i run `ls -l` after i've created TMPFILE I get:

```
total 4
-rwxrwxrwx 1 bristena bristena 530 may 25 10:51 sh.01
```

if i do `cd /tmp` and then I run  `ls -l` I get

```
total 12
drwx------ 3 root root 4096 may 25 10:14 systemd-private-long number-colord.service-LTsv8G
drwx------ 3 root root 4096 may 25 10:14 systemd-private-long number-rtkit-daemon.service-KQN6zN
drwx------ 3 root root 4096 may 25 10:14 systemd-private-long number-systemd-timesyncd.service-PxhNq0
-rw------- 1 bristena bristena 0 may 25 10:51 tmp.j0rvQtmz7G
```

from what I've seen online I can also use `trap "rm -f TMPFILE; exit"`, but I don't know how to integrate the current user requirenment

All of your help would be deeply appreciated

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and I am running this as a user. As for the files that trigger the error I'm not really sure, the errors look like this : '/tmp/systemd-private-long number-colord.service-LTsv8G' : permission denied  ; '/tmp/systemd-private-long number-systemd-timesyncd.service-PxhNq0' : permission denied ; '/tmp/systemd-private-long number-rtkit-daemon.service-KQN6zN' : permission denied

Comment: if i run ls -l after i've created TMPFILE I get: 
total 4
-rwxrwxrwx 1 bristena bristena 530 may 25 10:51 sh.01
if i do cd /tmp and then I run  ls -l I get
total 12
drwx------ 3 root root 4096 may 25 10:14 systemd-private-long number-colord.service-LTsv8G
drwx------ 3 root root 4096 may 25 10:14 systemd-private-long number-rtkit-daemon.service-KQN6zN
drwx------ 3 root root 4096 may 25 10:14 systemd-private-long number-systemd-timesyncd.service-PxhNq0
-rw------- 1 bristena bristena 0 may 25 10:51 tmp.j0rvQtmz7G

Comment: I'm ready, it's edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to avoid the error messages of

```
find /tmp -type f -user $USER -exec rm -f {} \;
```

you can either redirect them

```
find /tmp -type f -user $USER -exec rm -f {} \; 2>/dev/null
```

or prevent `find` from running into that problem:

```
find /tmp \( -type d \( -executable -o -prune \) \) -o -type f -user $USER -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Answer (score 2):

With `find /tmp -type f -user $USER -exec rm -f {} \;` you are telling `find` to go find and delete any files owned by `$USER` in *everywhere under* `/tmp`.

Now, your `/tmp` contains sub-directories that are owned by root. In theory they *could* contain more files owned by `$USER`. So `find` will try to peek into those directories to look for them. But the root-owned directories have permissions `drwx------`, so only root will be able to access them in any way.

As a result, `find` will report the directories it failed to enter, to tell you that it could not search *everywhere* under `/tmp` and so it might theoretically have missed something.

Scripts that run at system startup will run as root unless specified otherwise, and so if you would run that same command in a system start-up script, it would have full access to all directories under `/tmp` and would not have this problem at all: `find` running as root would be able to perform an exhaustive search into all directories under `/tmp`.

But if you run it as your own user account, then you would have to either ignore the "permission denied" errors since you expect them, or perform a more complicated search that first looks for directories `$USER` can access under `/tmp` and then removes any files in them.

Or if you're only looking for temporary files created by the same script, then you would want to look at temporary files in the `/tmp` directory *only*, and ignore any sub-directories of `/tmp`. If you want to do this, google on how to use the `-prune` option of `find`; it's a bit tricky one.

The `trap` command is slightly different. It can be used to ensure that your script will always clean up its temporary files (unless killed by an uncatchable signal like `SIGKILL` or a system crash). In a POSIX-compatible shell you would use it like this:

```
TMPFILE=$(mktemp)|| exit 1
trap "rm -f $TMPFILE" EXIT
```

In this `trap` command, `EXIT` is not a command, but the condition that will cause the trap to be triggered. The condition can be a signal, or a special value `0` or `EXIT`. Both of those two special values will mean "this trap action should be executed whenever this shell process is exiting for any reason."

Answer (score 0):

This one is nice, you even can add the days `-atime +3` files 3 days old

```
find /tmp \( -type d \( -executable -o -prune \) \) -o -type f -atime +3  -user $USER -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Comment: This looks like a copy/paste of a previous answer with the addition of the `-mtime` argument. Minor enough addition that it should be a comment to the accepted answer, not an answer in its own right.